# Json Web Token verify() return jwt malformed

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, postman

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const SECRET = "superSuperSecret";

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers[ "x-access-token" ];
    if (token) {
        return jwt.verify(token, SECRET, function(err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({
                    success: false,
                    message: "Failed to authenticate token.",
                });
            }
            req.user = decoded;
            return next();
        });
    }
    return res.unauthorized();
};
```

I'm using Postman to test my API. I setup the header with a `x-access-token` key and the value `superSuperSecret`. I got the error `{"name":"JsonWebTokenError","message":"jwt malformed","level":"error"}`. I'm using this https://github.com/FortechRomania/express-mongo-example-project/blob/master/src/middlewares/validateToken.js

Comment: What is the value of `token` you are getting after console?

Comment: @SookieSingh `superSuperSecret`

Comment: Also I think that jwt.verfy with a callback is a async function

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You cannot pass any value as token. You need `jwt.sign()` to create a token. Look at the documentation of [JWT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) for more information.

Also,

For the request Header name just use `Authorization` not `x-access-token`. Place Bearer before the Token.

```
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_STRING
```

Each part of the JWT is a base64url encoded value. You can get your token as:

```
var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
```

Comment: what is TOKEN_STRING?

Comment: Can you please look into my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65277469/jsonwebtokenerror-jwt-malformed-creating-an-api-in-expressjs

Comment: @TM TOKEN_STRING is the JWT(JSON Web Token) you get from the server after you log in to the system. For every request, you send from the client to the server(only for protected routes) you will have to append the token in the Authorization header so the server knows that the request is an authenticated request.

Answer (score 15):

**Note** :

JWT will return  **jwt malformed** If Token is null/Invalid-Signature that is being passed to jwt.verifty function

> let token = null;
> let payload = jwt.verify(token, 'secretKey');  //
> ERROR : jwt malformed

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I need your help.

Comment: See this is my code: `let payLoad = { subject: user._id }; let token = jwt.sign(payLoad, 'secretKey');`

Comment: @Tanzeel can u share your code (middleware), I want to see, in order to help?

Comment: Yes sure. Here it is: https://github.com/tmtanzeel/socialcoderapinodejs/blob/main/routes/api.js

Comment: Here I've opened a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65277469/jsonwebtokenerror-jwt-malformed-creating-an-api-in-expressjs

Comment: @Tanzeel I have tested your code by running on local server, and figure out the problem mentioned there  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65277469/jsonwebtokenerror-jwt-malformed-creating-an-api-in-expressjs/65278580#65278580

Answer (score 5):

From what I see, you are not sending the actual JWT token but the secret instead. A valid JWT token consist of a three-part string delimited by dots, like so:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c

https://jwt.io/

As you can see on the above website, 'superSuperSecret' is not a valid JWT token.

Comment: Then what is the solution. My code is also generating the same token. This code I have: `let payLoad = { subject: user._id };
                let token = jwt.sign(payLoad, 'secretKey');
                res.status(200).send({ token, userData, user });`

Answer (score 2):

From client side token can be passes as null or blank string, then this error will genrated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The same problems seems in my case due to invalid token format. A token consists of three parts: Header, payload and signature separated by dot (.). 
 
In my case, i am using token like this: `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9_eyJpZCI6IjY0NzcxYjg2YTQ4MGY2MTI3NDk3ODRhOCIsImlhdCI6MTY4NTUyNzQzMCwiZXhwIjoxNjg1NTI3NzMwfQ_WNToTRU6H5Qm30S0xH3cjU1LK9l8IAejXVrd2XdSMRw` 
Which is totally stupid error in my case. Instead of using `_` this separator i have to use dot `.` as a separator 
`(header.payload.signature)`
 for correct format. so jwt.verify() can handle this.
I hope you understand what causes an error.
`Note: If there is more underscore _ on your token then during conversion of _ to . also leads you on problem.`

Answer (score 0):

Token consists of 3 parts delimited by dots. There is a code from jsonwebtoken below

```js
var parts = jwtString.split('.');

if (parts.length !== 3){
  return done(new JsonWebTokenError('jwt malformed'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually stems from when the value of JWT isn't available to be read at all. Check and make sure the token is available at all; maybe on the environment variable on your postman or any other API testing software you're using

Answer (score 0):

Postman router from which is return jwt malformed, go to test options and skip pm.environment.set("jwt", pm.response.json().token);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The verification of token is not possible if token is not assigned.

```
function getUser(token){
    if(!token) return null;
    try {
    return jwt.verify(token ,secret);
        
    } catch (error) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).