# How to use protected api routes and verify JWT tokens with Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt

I am trying to achieve an register and login system , Currently I am able to register and store the data in the database and also login as I have tested it and I used a `console.log(token);` to see if I was being a token. However after loggin in I got to my webpage (React Component) /Profile which fetches a GET users/current  but I receive this in my console.

```
GET /users/current 401 2.083 ms - 33
```

Also in my browser console

```
 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
```

I feel like the token is not being passed correctly, I am new to using JWT so any help is useful.

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var morgan = require('morgan');
const auth = require('./middleware/auth');
const User = require('./models/User');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);

// use morgan to log requests to the console
app.use(morgan('dev'));

var Users = require('./routes/Users');

app.use('/users', Users);

// Create a Server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000; // Environment variable or port 5000

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

User.js

```
const express = require('express');
const users = express.Router();
const cors = require('cors');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const User = require('../models/User');
const config = require('config');
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');


users.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);

users.use(bodyParser.json());

users.use(cors());

users.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const today = new Date();
  const userData = {
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    created: today
  };

  User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email
    }
  })
    //TODO bcrypt
    //Need validation to appear on console and in view
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
          userData.password = hash;
          User.create(userData)
            .then(user => {
              res.json({ status: user.email + 'Registered!' });
            })
            .catch(err => {
              res.send('error: ' + err);
            });
        });
      } else {
        res.json({ error: 'User already exists' });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send('error: ' + err);
    });
});

users.post('/authenticate', (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email
    }
  }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
        const payload = {
          check: true
        };

        const token = jwt.sign(payload, config.get('myprivatekey'), {
          expiresIn: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
        });

        res.json({
          message: 'authentication done ',
          token: token
        });
        console.log('Successful Login');
        console.log(user.first_name);
      } else {
        res.json({ message: 'please check your password !' });
        console.log('incorrect password');
      }
    } else {
      res.json({ message: 'user not found !' });
      console.log('user cannot be found');
    }
  });
});

users.get('/current', auth, async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).select('-password');
  console.log(user);
  res.send(user);
});
```

Auth.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('config');

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  //get the token from the header if present
  const token = req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.headers['authorization'];
  //if no token found, return response (without going to the next middelware)
  if (!token) return res.status(401).send('Access denied. No token provided.');

  try {
    //if can verify the token, set req.user and pass to next middleware
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('myprivatekey'));
    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (ex) {
    //if invalid token
    res.status(400).send('Invalid token.');
  }
};
```

/Profile web page (React Component)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import axios from 'axios';

class Profile extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      email: '',
      errors: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/users/current')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(myJson) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='jumbotron mt-5'>
          <div className='col-sm-8 mx-auto'>
            <h1 className='text-center'>PROFILE</h1>
          </div>
          <table className='table col-md-6 mx-auto'>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>{this.state.first_name}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td>{this.state.last_name}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>{this.state.email}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Profile;
```

Comment: Offtopic: keep in mind that jwt's can be bruteforced, when that happens attackers can make there own jwt and sign it..

Comment: @RaymondNijland what do you suggest?

Comment: instead of using JWT for login . is session betteR?

Comment: Research the matter some algorithms are prone

Comment: what line in the code is the syntax error coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the code for cors and bodyparser in server.js only. No need to use it in User.js. Use express-jwt for JWT authentication.

```
var jwt = require('express-jwt');

users.get('/current', jwt({secret: config.get('myprivatekey')}), async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).select('-password');
  console.log(user);
  res.send(user);
});
```

Please refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt

Also send the token in header for fetch

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/users/current', {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz',
    },
})
```

Please replace `xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz` with the JWT token.

Comment: Thanks I shall try this . what should go into x , y and z. Sorry im new to using JWT

Comment: Welcome. You will get the token when you authenticate using http://localhost:5000/users/authenticate . You should store that token in localStorage  and send it in the header when you access a protected API. JWT contains three parts. I mentioned xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz as a placeholder. Please refer [https://jwt.io/introduction/](https://jwt.io/introduction/) for details

Comment: still having problems with the headers. unsure what to include after authotization: 'Bearing x.y.z'. also how do I store it as localstorage to i  just do this before the fetch?? const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

Comment: I know that it requires the header , payload and signature but how do you retreive that

Comment: According to your code a token is returned on successful authentication. You should store this token in localStorage. Please refer [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for details on localStorage.  The token can be retrieved and passed along with the header for fetch ```const token = localStorage.getItem('token'); fetch('http://localhost:5000/users/current', {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token,
    },
})```

Comment: I have done what you suggested , but receiving this error. UnauthorizedError: jwt malformed. found this but not sure if thats whats wrong. I receive this error when I go to my /Profile webpage which fetches /user/current. would it be due to refreshing the page?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51849010/json-web-token-verify-return-jwt-malformed/51849197

Comment: Please check if you are getting the token value before fetch by doing a console.log

Comment: Below is the console.log(token); 
 
 eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjaGVjayI6dHJ1ZSwiaWF0IjoxNTYzMDI1NDE3LCJleHAiOjE1NjMwMjY4NTd9.iUcfSPkzV46q5CoIHiCBhFOK2D08HUFbyJevD_7ufAM .https://jwt.io/ this website , says its an invalid signature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196418/discussion-between-john-and-arun-devarajan).