# JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed (creating an API in ExpressJs)

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I've checked many answers on the internet but I think I'm doing some other mistake also. My question is strictly related to guarding `/contribute` route using JWT (which is a POST request). My API is in `expressjs`. First I hit `/login` route with correct credentials and get a token. This token I cross checked on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and it says "Invalid Signature".
Here is that token:
`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWJqZWN0IjoiNWVhZDlkOGY4N2VjMjkwMDE3YzRkODkzIiwiaWF0IjoxNjA3ODczNjY2fQ.H5RI-lOBzfJo4_FgParuJA4ULnJ_An6uihiF31bzNtU`

Then I would hit `/contribute` route with the same token. Here is my code:

**api.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
...
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
...
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    let userData = req.body
    User.findOne({ email: userData.email }, (error, user) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        } else {
            if (!user) {
                res.status(401).send('Invalid email')
            } else if (user.password !== userData.password) {
                res.status(401).send('Invalid password')
            } else {
                let payLoad = { subject: user._id };  // tried { subject: 'foobar' } also
                let token = jwt.sign(payLoad, 'secretKey');
                res.status(200).send({ token, userData, user });
            }
        }
    })
})

router.post('/contribute', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    console.log('Pushing new article');
    let userPost = req.body;
    let post = new Post(userPost);
    post.save((error, registeredPost) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(registeredPost);
        }
    })
})

function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.headers.authorization) {
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request')
    }
    let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    if (token === 'null') {
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request')
    }
    let payload = jwt.verify(token, 'secretKey')
    if (!payload) {
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request')
    }
    req.userId = payload.subject
    next()
}

module.exports = router;
```

But the moment I hit `/contribute` I get this:

> JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed
> at Object.module.exports [as verify] (C:\Users\320050772\Documents\socialcoderapinodejs\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:63:17)
> at verifyToken (C:\Users\320050772\Documents\socialcoderapinodejs\routes\api.js:86:23)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\320050772\Documents\socialcoderapinodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (C:\Users\320050772\Documents\socialcoderapinodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\320050772\Documents\socialcoderapinodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\320050772\Documents\socialcoderapinodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

Please point out my mistake.

I checked on Postman also. Token is generated but again it is invalid. Why my code is generating invalid tokens.

Comment: *I cross checked on jwt.io and it says "Invalid Signature"* - this usually happens, when you don't paste the secret or key into the field in the right column. Without knowing the key jwt.io can't verify the signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It been noticed that **Generated Token is valid**. But its not been reaching to backend with upcoming next call e.g Post of /contribute. showing some non-valid value.
Therefore, let the valid token to be arrived on Backend so that jwt.varify could validate it correctly.

Comment: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: copy first line too  = router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {

Comment: ya I copied whole of it

Comment: nope :-(
Can we have an online call please. I'll share my screen.

Comment: sure, we can have. share zoom link

Comment: Plz join this :  https://us04web.zoom.us/j/73752046511?pwd=bzVtY2lTVFhPRkY2RzF4OUo4NVFoUT09

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistake. I'll update my code accordingly and you can edit the answer so that i can accept. Give me some time. :-)

Comment: OK, @Tanzeel  I will

Answer (score 0):

Bro I checked your code, all is OK, `verifyToken` ✅ , (though not the User and Post objects) make sure you send the authorisation header correctly like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWJqZWN0IjoiMTIzNDQ1IiwiaWF0IjoxNjA3ODgwMjkwfQ.zJbcqM8yBRABxhm5BgQNow1gmzsgUjiLdPdv7Tq5ND4
```

I used the code from your example and modified a bit

```
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('123'));

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  let payLoad = { subject: '123445' };
  let token = jwt.sign(payLoad, 'secretKey');
  res.status(200).send({ token });
});

app.post('/contribute', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
  res.send('i can reach here...');
});

function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.headers.authorization) {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request');
  }
  let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  if (token === 'null') {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request');
  }
  let payload = jwt.verify(token, 'secretKey');
  if (!payload) {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request');
  }
  req.userId = payload.subject;
  next();
}

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server on 3000'));
```