# JWT Auth Token Error - Can't create chatroom, JWT malformed

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt

I'm building login system for my ChatApp and got stuck on JWT malformed when trying to create a new chatroom. When I login I get token and I try to send request from Postman to create chatroom, I put Token as bearer and in body I set name as my chatroom which is ok to put. Code:

auth.js:

```
const jwt = require('jwt-then')
module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (!req.headers.authorization) throw 'Forbidden!'
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split('')[1]

        const payload = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET)

        req.payload = payload

        next()
    } catch (err){
        res.status(401).json({
            message: err.message
        })
    }

}
```

routes/chatroom.js:

```
const { catchErrors } = require('../handlers/errorHandlers.js')
const chatroomController = require('../controllers/userControllers.js')


const auth = require('../middlewares/auth')

router.post('/', auth, catchErrors(chatroomController.createChatroom))


module.exports = router
```

chatroomController:

```
const Chatroom = mongoose.model('Chatroom')

exports.createChatroom = async (req, res) => {
    const {name} = req.body

    const nameRegex = /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/

    if (!nameRegex.test(name)) throw 'Chatroom name can only contain alphabets.'

    const chatroomExists = await Chatroom.findOne({name})

    if (chatroomExists) throw 'Chatroom already exists.'

    const chatroom = new Chatroom({
        name,
    })

    await chatroom.save()

    res.json({
        message: 'Chatroom created!',
    })
 }
```

Please help me

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51849010/json-web-token-verify-return-jwt-malformed

Comment: What then I need to do?

Comment: Did you take a look at the first answer in the link I sent you?  I think it has some useful information. 

Comment: It is useful, but I don't know where should I put jwt.sign()?

Comment: You can put `jwt.sign()` wherever you're creating your tokens.

Comment: Idk, I was just following tutorial and everything worked fine for that dude, I don't even know where tokens are being created.

Comment: Where do you recommend?

Comment: Ohh, I see.  Which tutorial is this?  It's not possible for JWT's to be verified if they haven't been created.  There must be a part he hasn't gotten to or that you've missed where he explains it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=edrFbieDmv8&t=353s Please, tell me if I missed something, Account registration and login was successful, but only when trying to create chatroom.

Comment: I don't have time to go through a whole tutorial now.
All I can tell you is that you're watching part 3 of this tutorial.  Did you start from part 1?

Comment: Of course! I started from 1st

Comment: I've builded ChatApp before and it works, now I'm building login system with tutorial where he builds ChatApp

Comment: Hmm, I see.  Well, I can definitely tell you that you'd usually create JWT when the user logs in.  Once the user logs in and the JWT has been created, you can send the JWT to the user in an HTTP only cookie, localStorage, or even memory.
That way, when the user makes a request that requires authorization/authentication, they can send that JWT token along with that request.

Comment: Well, I'm beginner to JS and I don't know much about cookies nor JWT

Comment: That's alright.  We all start somewhere.  I'm trying to find where we can chat haha, cuz this is getting long.

Comment: Maybe the problem is causing that I haven't put require('./models/Message.js'), when I put it as the dude in tutorial did, I get an error OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Message` model once compiled.

Comment: Message.js Code: ```const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    chatroom: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: 'Chatroom is required!',
        ref: 'Chatroom',
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: 'Chatroom is required!',
        ref: 'User'
    },
    message: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Message is required!',
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema)```

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: Here's a link to a room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233141/jwt

Comment: Myb Insta chat?

Comment: Just click on the link I sent

Comment: I don't have 20 reputation

Comment: And I can't. Maybe try Instagram DM or WAP

Comment: Oh snap.  Do you have discord?

Comment: Oh, I actually have another solution.

Comment: Yes, I will send you now my name

Comment: Which one solution?

Comment: This is a chat app I made a while ago.  We can chat here for now. xD  https://2chsr.csb.app/

Comment: Well, i don't see you

Comment: Sorry, was talking to someone.  I'm there.  I see your messages