# Cannot verify JWT - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I have function that just send data to database (my posts). I use private and public keys to sign and verify tokens. I can send this token in header from front-end to back-end, but has problem with verifying it. Here is how this flow looks like:

### Front-end

```js
router.post(`/p-p`, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await api.post(`/post-post`, req.body, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + req.body.token
      }
    })
    res.json(data.data)
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(e.response.status).json(e.response.data)
  }
})
```

### Back-end

```js
router.post(
  "/post-post",
  auth,
  wrapAsync(generalController.postPost)
)
```

#### Middleware auth

```js
const jwtService = require('./../services/jwtService')

module.exports = async(req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers.authorization) {
    const user = await jwtService.getUser(req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1])
    if (user) {
      next();
    } else {
      res.status(401).json({
        error: 'Unauthorized'
      })
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({
      error: 'Unauthorized'
    })
  }
}
```

#### And JWT service

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const pathToKeys = path.resolve(__dirname, "../../keys");

module.exports = {
  sign(payload) {
    const cert = fs.readFileSync(`${pathToKeys}/private.pem`);
    return jwt.sign(
      payload,
      {
        key: cert,
        passphrase: process.env.JWT_PASSPHRASE
      },
      {
        algorithm: "RS256",
        expiresIn: "30m"
      }
    )
  },
  getUserPromise(token) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      jwt.verify(token, fs.readFileSync(`${pathToKeys}/public.pem`), (err, decoded) => {
        if(!err) {
          return resolve(decoded);
        } else {
          return reject(err);
        }
      })
    })
  },
  async getUser (token) {
    return await this.getUserPromise(token)
  }
}
```

The problem starts after `getUserPromise` function. This function can get a token, but can't verify it and I have this problem:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed`

Actually, I have no idea where problem is. I generated key pair, and `sign` function can sing and return token, which looks like this: `351e38a4bbc517b1c81e180479a221d404c724107988852c7768d813dd0510e6183306b1d837091b2cddaa07f2427b7a`

So, what's the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you're using a valid token? I've only seen JWTs as three dot-separated Base64 strings, and you seem to be passing a hexadecimal value (and a short one at that). See e.g. [the jwt.io getting started page](https://jwt.io/introduction) for the usual format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Json Web Token verify() return jwt malformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51849010/json-web-token-verify-return-jwt-malformed)

Comment: I don't see where and how you call the sign function, but inside of it you call jwt.sign and return it as a result, not sure how you can get a hexadecimal string out of it. The hex string is clearly not a JWT, not sure how or where you got this from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution of this problem and it feels shame. In JWT service pay attention to this string:

`algorithm: "RS256"`

As you can see I use `RS256`, but I generated certificates in other format, so, because of this I got that error.

So, if you use RSA certificates, pay attention to algorithm!

EDIT:

Here is how you can generate pair for RS256:

1. Private

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem -aes256 4096
```

2. Public from private

```
openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout > public.pem
```